# Devise Registration edit by user role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, user-roles

I've been having an issue fully grasping how to separate my application by user role.

My goal is to have a user signup via one registration and to be rooted to a specific root along with specific layout with different devise account information.

- Any user no matter the role will be able register by username email, password. But after registration will be required to enter additional account info if the role requires.
- Example regular user just needs username password email.
- Vip would need name address username password email.

So far I have my roles set up within my devise user model

```
ROLES w% [ regular vip1 vip]
```

I've set up a separate controller to redirect current user by role to a specific path.

```
def index
    path = case current_user.role
      when 'regular
      edit_user_registration_path
else.... etc etc
```

I also overridden devise registration controller to include roles on sign up.

My issue is still finding a way to assign layouts by user role and require additional account information by role as well. And even though I've found a way to redirect a user by role. It would be much easier to find a way to redirect user after sign up to a specific page and root a user by role.

I've also looked through CanCanCan docs and understand the concept of  limiting different features per user role for example one user having the ability to create a post and another not. Which is really valuable for the application I'm planning to build but is there anything that explains how to root and render different layouts per user.

Also I'm open to a different strategy that might help separate users by role but still has the convenience of one common login and signup. Last but not least I also plan to add one click sign on from sites like twitter and facebook, when dealing with user role would you expect an issue down the road?

Any ideas or advice would help. again I've read thoroughly on cancancan and devise I'm either totally missing something or completely confused.

Any help I would be the utmost grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format it using markdown bullets. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Last, I fixed some minor grammar and spelling. Please edit to add any ore details in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can handle this.
Inside the controller, you can specify which views/layouts you want to render.
For instance:

```
if current_user.role == "vip"
  render layout: "vip"
elsif current_user.role == "regular"
  render layout: "regular"
end
```

However, instead of making a bunch of different layouts and views, you could have one view that only displays certain fields dependent on user roles.

That would look something like this (in HAML):

```
-if current_user.role == "vip"
  =f.input :address
  =f.input :name
=f.input :email
=f.input :password
```

As for 1-click signup via 3rd party OAuth, I don't imagine that would be a huge problem. When your app receives a callback after someone has logged in via Facebook or Twitter, the controller that receives that callback can handle assigning the different roles.

Comment: That makes alot of sense thank you, displaying information within the same views makes much more sense, any thoughts about rooting the user by role and have a special condition for after signup per user role. I've read the devise documents and searched up and down stack overflow with no success. The only success that gets me closer but hasn't solved my issue is creating a new controller that redirects a user by role.

Comment: within my pages controller I defined index                                                   def index                                                                                      path = case current_user.role                                                              when 'regular'                                                                                  edit_user_registration_path                                                                        end

Comment: so far that has worked out well, and it seems like it would work to establish a root by user root, my issue is finding a convenient way to redirect a user by role after signup, and anytime after they sign up they will just be redirected to the standard root for that specific role